# How to make android round buttons

Tags: android, button

I have tried to search this a lot however I was not able to make the same buttons as in the picture for android.

[image]

I have been trying to use the following code but the button is not transparent and it doesn't have that nice rounding on the sides:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Currently it looks like this

[image]

I want the EditTexts and the buttons to be transparent with a white border
It would be a great great help if someone could assist me on this.

Comment: It isn't transparent because you have defined your color with `ee` alpha

Comment: @cricket_007, I have deleted those two 'ee' still won't give me the nice roundings and transparency as in the picture above

Comment: Can you upload what it currently looks like? I think you just have a `solid` white button with some rounded corners, yes?

Comment: Use `<stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="2dp" />` instead of `<solid android:color="#ffffff" />`

Comment: @cricket_007 please refer to the picture below. Thank you

Comment: @thetonrifles You are welcome to make than an answer

Comment: @Nant Better you delete your answer and update just your question in case of new relevant updates. Right now I'm not sure about where to write comments for keeping discussion clear :)

Comment: So, I liked that original login screen so much that I rewrote it myself. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining shape is proper approach. If you want it to be transparent with white border you need to avoid using solid tag and use stroke (that is the border).

So for example you will have this shape (let's call it `bg_button.xml` under `drawable` folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

Apply then this to your views as background. This is an example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Facebook"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"/>
```

Please try this not just on Android Studio editor but also on your emulator / device. Rendering of rounded corners on Android Studio editor can create problems.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a xml drawable called rounded_button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#6E6E6E"/> 

<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

You then set the background of the button to the @drawable resource you created.